# ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier -- Dynamic Oracle function

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
    create or replace 
    FUNCTION JDT_UDC_Desc
    (
     V_SY IN VARCHAR2,
      V_RT IN VARCHAR2,
      V_KY IN VARCHAR2
    )
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS
       V_DL01 VARCHAR2(30);


BEGIN



   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select drdl01 
       from PRODCTL.F0005
              WHERE DRSY = V_SY
     AND DRRT = V_RT
      AND ltrim(rtrim(drky)) =ltrim(rtrim(V_KY))'
INTO V_DL01
using V_SY,V_RT,V_KY;
END;
```

---

Compiled. I click on run and enter below values:

```
 V_SY ='00',
V_RT = '01',
V_KY='04';
```

And I get below error

> ORA-00904 V_KY Invalid Identifier

Can anyone help me understand the reason for this error?

Comment: First, there does not appear to be any reason to use dynamic SQL here.  It should be rare that you need to resort to dynamic SQL-- your code is going to be more efficient and more maintainable if you stick with static SQL.

Comment: @JustinCave i want this function to use dynamic variable and not static. Values V_SY, V_RT and V_KY are dynamic variables. I understand static would be fine but need it for an application purpose

Comment: That does not require using dynamic SQL.  You'd use dynamic SQL if the name of the table you want to query or the columns you wanted to return would only be known at runtime.  Static SQL is perfectly capable of dealing with queries where the value of a bind variable is determined at runtime.  In fact, 99.99% of all static SQL in real applications use variables/ parameters whose values are not known until runtime.

Comment: @JustinCave thanks for the information. can you help me understand how can i get output with above query or is there any  other alternative? My requirement is that I need to enter my IN parameters when I click on run and then the function should return value

Comment: @JustinCave    `select functionname(parameters) from tablename ...... (my parameters will vary each time)`                                                           I should be able to get my function output by this query

Comment: Are you working with someone else that is posting similar questions here?  I'm almost positive that someone yesterday was posting questions with exactly the same variable names and dealing with very similar problems.  But I'm not quite finding the duplicate question.

Comment: @JustinCave it is only me who is working in this project as of now

Comment: Ahh, just realized that you asked a similar question on DBA yesterday, that's why the code looked so familiar http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154993/use-of-ref-cursor-for-select-into-where-output-multiple-rows

Comment: @JustinCave yes true that i posted it but it was not yesterday November 11, 10 days back but I am still stuck in that same problem :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there does not appear to be any reason to use dynamic SQL here.  It should be rare that you need to resort to dynamic SQL-- your code is going to be more efficient and more maintainable.

```
create or replace 
    FUNCTION JDT_UDC_Desc
    (
      V_SY IN VARCHAR2,
      V_RT IN VARCHAR2,
      V_KY IN VARCHAR2
    )
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS
       V_DL01 VARCHAR2(30);
    BEGIN
      select drdl01 
        into V_DL01
        from PRODCTL.F0005
       WHERE DRSY = V_SY
         AND DRRT = V_RT
         AND trim(drky) =trim(V_KY);

      return v_dl01;
    END;
```

Second, it would be really helpful if you picked meaningful variable names and meaningful names for your columns and tables.  `F0005` tells you nothing about what the table contains.  `v_sy` and `drsy` tell you nothing about what the variable or column is supposed to contain.  That is going to make maintaining this code far more difficult that it needs to be.

Comment: These tables are not created by me. We can only access this table via dblink like tablename@dblink_instance name. I tried the above code it gave me error  'ORA-01403: no data found'                                                                ------------------------------------                                                            `select DRDL01 FROM PRODCTL WHERE DRSY = '00' AND DRRT = '01' AND ltrim(rtrim(drky)) = '04'`                                                         this returns 1 record when i check in editor

Comment: This function is somehow not taking values of V_SY, V_RT and V_KY during run time

Comment: @Simi - You're going to have to be more specific than "somehow not taking values".  If you're getting an ORA-01403: no data found exception, then the row doesn't exist at least in the context of the session it is running in.  Perhaps someone inserted a row in a different transaction that hasn't yet been committed.  That would make the row visible to the session that inserted it but not to a different session.

Comment: Oracle databases are not currently in use except by me. Only I am using it in my company as of now to build some functions and procedure since all our applications are connected to MS SQL server. There are no users, no other developers inserting, deleting or updating any records so it is cannot be said that there are other transactions taking place. please clear me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Simi - If you have two different sessions, you can do an `insert` in one session and the data will not be visible to the other session until the first session commits.  If the issue is not one of transaction scope, then you'll need to post a complete test case that reproduces your problem.  Perhaps some of the columns are `char` rather than `varchar2` for example.

Comment: yes i doubt the same. I should try using different data type and check now

Comment: finally i am so excited to say that it worked for me.... My input parameters were in CHAR datatype and I assumed them as varchar2 which was wrong. So finally my function is working now. Thank you so much @Justin cave for all your help.

Comment: @Simi - This is why putting together a complete, reproducible test case is so helpful.  If you had posted that 10 days ago, I'd wager that the problem would have been solved in a few minutes.  When you don't have a complete, reproducible test case, we can't see what you're seeing and we have to do a lot of guessing in the dark.

Comment: Yes you are right will give a complete and reproducible test cases from now. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the literal values 'V_SY', 'V_RT' and 'V_KY' in your statement and it's interpreting them as column names, hence the invalid identifier error.  You need to use the variable placeholders like:

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select drdl01 
          from PRODCTL.F0005
          WHERE DRSY = :1
          AND DRRT = :2
          AND ltrim(rtrim(drky)) =ltrim(rtrim(:3))'
 INTO V_DL01
 using V_SY,V_RT,V_KY;
```

Comment: I get error no data found with this code. I entered values as 00, 01, 04

Comment: Copy & paste the select statement with those values and run them directly in your editor and see if it returns any data.

Comment: `select DRDL01 FROM PRODCTL WHERE DRSY = '00' AND DRRT = '01' AND ltrim(rtrim(drky)) = '04'` this returned 1 record

Comment: i tried this code in function                                                           `SELECT drdl01

     INTO V_DL01
     FROM  PRODCTL.F0005
     WHERE DRSY  = '00'
     
             AND DRRT = '01' AND
            LTRIM(RTRIM(DRKY)) = '04';
           RETURN V_DL01;` ............. the function works and gives me 1 record but I want this function to be dynamic and not static

Comment: OK, so go ahead and put single quotes around the placeholders, i.e., `WHERE DRSY = ':1'` etc.

Comment: I do not wish to enter values V_SY, V_RT, V_KY in function. These  are my IN parameters and I want to enter them only after I click on RUN button. so that anytime I can use this code and get output                             `select functionname(parameters) from tablename`                         ...... (my parameters will vary every time)